# Meaning of this mathematical symbol

Tags: notation, tensors

I am reading through the book,  "Tensor Algebra and Tensor Analysis" by Itskov and he uses this symbol without definition.   What does it mean?  Is the inferred meaning (from the context)  the general definition?   What is this symbol called?    I am referring to the large caret over the cross sign in the image.

Thanks

[image: The large caret over the cross sign on line two]

Comment: That “caret” is usually read *hat*.

Comment: I'd guess $\widehat{g_j\times g_i}=g_i\otimes g_j-g_j\otimes g_i$, seeing as the coefficients are the same and $g_j\otimes g_i-g_i\otimes g_j$ for $j<i$ are a basis of $\bigwedge^3W$

Comment: My guess too,  but I was more asking if that is a general definition,  and what is the name of the combined symbol if it has one (Caret plus cross).

Comment: Usually, a hat over a vector means "that vector, but scaled to have norm 1" ($\hat{u} = \frac{u}{\|u\|}$). Does it make sense in context for this to just mean $$\widehat{\mathbf g_j \times \mathbf g_i} = \frac{\mathbf g_j \times \mathbf g_i}{\| \mathbf g_j \times \mathbf g_i \|}?$$